# What do you call the random Gaussian vectors in compressed sensing?

Tags: compressive-sensing, soft-question

Let $(e_i)_{1\leq i\leq M}$ be vectors with zero-mean i.i.d. entries from a Gaussian distribution. In a compressed-sensing setup, I have observed the collection of scalar products $(\langle x\, |\, e_i\rangle)_{1\leq i\leq M}$ for an unknown vector $x$.

> In the compressed sensing literature, what is the name for the collection of vectors   $(e_i)_{1\leq i\leq M}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection of scalar products is often called *measurement*. The collection of vectors (each being an *atom*) can be called *measurement dictionaries* or *sensing dictionaries*. This is not specific to random atoms.

Answer (score 2):

In most of the literature I am familiar with (signal processing), these vectors are considered collectively as rows in a matrix, i.e.
$$\mathbf y = \mathbf E \mathbf x$$
where the $(M \times 1)$ vector $\mathbf y$ contains the measurements, i.e. the inner products of the Gaussian vectors $\mathbf e_i$ with $\mathbf x$. The sparse vector $\mathbf x$ is $(N \times 1)$. NB, I prefer to use bold notation for vectors and matrices.
Hence this $(M \times N)$ matrix collection of vectors is called the maesurement matrix.

I am reluctant to call it a measurement *dictionary* as in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70987/1464), because in a lot of literature, the matrix that takes you from the sparse vector $\mathbf x$ to the measurements $\mathbf y$ is factored into a *measurement* matrix (here $\mathbf E$) and a *dictionary* matrix or *sparsifying dictionary* $\mathbf D$ - typically $(N \times N)$ matrix:
$$\mathbf y = \mathbf{EDx} = \mathbf{Ax}$$
This factorisation is especially important in applications where the compressed sensing equation represents a physical phenomenon where the observable signal $\mathbf z = \mathbf{Dx}$ is not necessarily sparse in the observable domain, but the measurement $\mathbf y = \mathbf {Ez}$ is the only way you physically have acces to measuring your signal. The interpretation $\mathbf z = \mathbf{Dx}$ is a mathematical abstraction you add to your model afterwards in order to apply compressed sensing to the reconstruction of the signal.